# How to use dplyr pipe to perform linear model

Tags: dplyr, tidyverse, lm, broom

I have the following data frame:

```
library(broom)
library(tidyverse)
dat <- structure(list(x = c(800, 400, 200, 100, 50), y = c(605, 467, 
323, 219, 110)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
dat
```

That looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1   800   605
2   400   467
3   200   323
4   100   219
5    50   110
```

What I'm trying to do is to fit lm using dplyr piping.
When I try this:

```
fit_conc_df <- dat %>% do(fit_conc = lm(y ~ x, data = .))
glance(fit_conc_df, fit_conc)
```

I get this message:

```
Error: There is no glance method for tibbles. Did you mean `tibble::glimpse()`?
```

What I hope to get is this (without piping):

```
 x <- c(50, 100, 200, 400, 800)
 y <- c(110, 219, 323, 467, 605)
 conc_fit <- lm(y ~ x)
 glance(conc_fit)
```

with this result:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 12
  r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC
      <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0.910         0.880  68.0      30.3  0.0118     1  -26.9  59.8  58.7
# … with 3 more variables: deviance <dbl>, df.residual <int>, nobs <int>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple. Don't overcomplicate.

```
fit_conc_df <- dat %>% lm(y ~ x, data = .)
fit_conc_df %>% 
  glance()

# A tibble: 1 x 12
  r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC
      <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0.910         0.880  68.0      30.3  0.0118     1  -26.9  59.8  58.7
# ... with 3 more variables: deviance <dbl>, df.residual <int>, nobs <int>
```

The reason your code was failing is because the pipe operator is passing the data as the first argument to the `lm()` function but you were also providing an argument name `fit_conc`.

Also, you can create the data frame/tibble much more concisely as follows:

```
 dat <- tibble(x = c(50, 100, 200, 400, 800), 
               y = c(110, 219, 323, 467, 605))
```